# IE 11 box shadow thinner than Chrome/Firefox

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

I apply same values for box-shadow property, but on IE11, the shadows seem thinner and I even can't see it in some case.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/anhhnt/8pvgZ/2/
Here is result of IE11 for who don't have this browser:
[image: 6]

The original property value is :

```
box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 0px #777;
```

When I change it into

```
box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px 0px #777;
```

... then it seems OK, but why there is this difference? and what is best solution to work around this?
Thanks in advanced

Comment: different browsers, different rendering. It's been the case since the very beginning. The default answer is this: use a media query or browser dependent css and modify it to be what you want.

Comment: Finally, I've chosen the solution: User different markup for different browser. It's much harder, but gives the same experience to user.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because each browser has it's own way of rendering elements.

The best way to work around this really is to make your page non-dependant on graphic elements that may differ from browser to browser (such as `box-shadow`). When i have to use `box-shadow`, i usually put an almost invisble one, with a subtle border. It works out really nice, and avoid most of the problems we usually have with the absurd difference between browsers' interpretation of the `box-shadow`property.

I made a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8pvgZ/3/) based on the one you posted.